# Same UV map for whole and shattered versions of object

Tags: uv

I have 2 versions of the object: whole and shattered. How can I use the same UV map (same texture) for both so I won't have to draw same thing twice and so textures match when I break the object in game? I understand that the shattered one will have extra polygons, but still both versions will have most parts in common. What is the best practice for this? Do I have just to match them all manually or maybe there is some addon that automatically creates UV for shattered version using UV of whole or else?

[image: Whole.]
[image: Shattered.]